# How to send a delta (differential part) of a large binary file over the Internet?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, compression, diff, binary-files

I have sent a large (>1GB) binary file to a friend over a slow metered data plan and now I need to send the second version of the same file only slightly changed. I want to send only the delta/diff-ed part of it to save the data plan and I want the recipient to easily patch it. We both are using Windows 7. What is the easiest and the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have you searched `Binary Diff`? There are a number of software packages, but this site isn't for software recommendations I'm afraid.

Comment: Or just use Dropbox, it will only push changed blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I used [xdelta](http://xdelta.org/) and [xdeltagui](http://thejbnet.com/progs/xgui/) for Windows to make an XZ-compressed patch file and apply it at the recipient's.

There is another [XDelta GUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xdeltagui/) too, but I have not tested it.